# Troubleshooting an Issue with the Instant Pot Duo Plus 6 Quart Model - Pot is Making Clicking Sounds When Preheating and Cooking

Tags: pressure-cooker, instant-pot

My 6 quart Instant Pot Duo Plus makes a clicking sound when it is preheating and cooking (it is still cooking right now; just started it a few hours ago). Please refer to the videos in the Reddit post here: https://www.reddit.com/r/PressureCooking/comments/14p7pnw/troubleshooting_an_issue_with_the_instant_pot_duo/. I only used the slow cooking option so far. For Instant Pot Duo Plus owners, has this happened with anyone, and how did you fix this? I had cancelled the slow cooking setting a few times, as I forgot to add a few ingredients. When I ran the cooker for the first time, I didn't hear the cooking sound. Is it possible that I may have broken something on the lid?

When I first used this, I did not familiarize myself with all of the parts (I've used an Instant Pot before), but when I was reading through the instruction manual, I saw that this model had a condensation collector, but initially could not find it. I started exploring the pot after cancelling the slow cook setting (after starting it for the first time). I explored the lid and initially removed the float valve plastic cover. I had trouble getting it back on (had to hold the valve to keep it from going back up when I turn the lid with the inside out. Did any of my actions break a part, leading to to clicking sound?

Any input regarding this would be much appreciated; thanks so much for reading!

Comment: Is the thing malfunctioning in any way you’re aware of, beyond making a clicking sound?